# Distinguishing between fact and dimension tables in data warehouse

Tags: data-warehouse, facttable

Is it true that facts in a fact table of a data warehouse always have a relation to time? I.e. is it true that a fact must always be assignable to a specific point in time?

If this is correct, can we conclude that dimension elements (except for maybe a time-dimension) do not need to be assignable to a specific point in time?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can yoy post link to where you read that?

Comment: Time itself, if it's part of the fact, is almost always a dimension. However, a fact may not necessarily have a time component.

Comment: @MichaelKutz, thanks for your comment. I could not find anything about fact tables in relation to time, so I asked it here. All I could find were the usual definitions that fact tables represent business facts and that they include measures like sales, etc.